# An elasticsearch query on an optionally absent field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an elastic index of simple objects that have two fields:

```
{
   "content": "something",
   "acl": ["andrey", "gilles"]
}
```

The `acl` field is an array of usernames, or a value "public", or it may not be present in an object at all. I want to write a query that gives me all objects where `acl=testuser` or it doesn't exist. This is my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool" : {
            "must": [
              {"exists" : { "field" : "acl" }},
              {"match" : {"acl":"testuser"}}
            ]
          },
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                "exists": {
                    "field": "acl"
                }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But whenI execute it I get an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 12,
        "col": 11
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
    "line": 12,
    "col": 11
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid:

1. You have a field `bool` set twice inside `should` query
2. `must_not` is an array, and you didn't add curly braces for a new object

Besides, you don't need `exist` query to match together with `match` query. So you just need to leave `match` query and `must_not` `exist` query inside `should` like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must_not": [
                            {
                                "exists": {
                                    "field": "acl"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "acl": "testuser"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```